# copy .tar.gz files to folder

Tags: java, vfs, truezip

I want to copy contents of a .tar.gz files to 2 folder , It has around 20 files and total unzipped size will be >20 GB.
          I used Truezip for this .

```
 TFile archive = new TFile(absoluteZipName); // archive with .tar.gz
    TFile[] archFiles = archive.listFiles(); // takes too much time 
    for (TFile t : archFiles) {
         String fileName = t.getName();
          if(fileName.endsWith(".dat"))
              t.cp(new File(destination1+ t.getName()));
          else if(fileName.endsWith(".txt")){
               t.cp(new File(destination2+ t.getName()));
          }
    }
 It takes 3 times above tar xzf command (untar linux) . Have any way to optimize this code for fast copying, memory not an issue.  

    The following code allows fast copying Thanks npe for the good advice.
    (NB: I have no previledge to post the answe now that's why editing question itself)

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(absoluteZipName);
            ArchiveInputStream input = new ArchiveStreamFactory()
               .createArchiveInputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.TAR, new GZIPInputStream(is));

            ArchiveEntry entry;
            while ((entry = input.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                OutputStream outputFileStream=null;
                if(entry.getName().endsWith(".dat")){
                 File outFile1= new File(destination1, entry.getName());
                     outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile1); 
                }
                else if(entry.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
                File outFile2= new File(destination2, entry.getName());
                     outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile2);   
                }
                // use ArchiveEntry#getName() to do the conditional stuff...
                IOUtils.copy(input, outputFileStream,10485760);
            }


    Is threading In file copy will reduce time..? In TZip didn't reduced as they already threading it. anyway I will try tomorrow and will let you Know.
```

Comment: do in 2 steps? tar -xzvf ./some/tmp/destination + 2 times the 'mv' command filtering on extensions? Or is it mandatory to be in java?

Comment: In this case, I don't think you can optimize that a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks npe , this is the final I have done, any way it tooks less time than tar xzf. Final code snippet like this.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(absoluteZipName);
ArchiveInputStream input = new ArchiveStreamFactory()
   .createArchiveInputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.TAR, new GZIPInputStream(is));

ArchiveEntry entry;
while ((entry = input.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    OutputStream outputFileStream=null;
    if(entry.getName().endsWith(".dat")){
     File outFile1= new File(destination1, entry.getName());
         outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile1); 
    }
    else if(entry.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
    File outFile2= new File(destination2, entry.getName());
         outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile2);   
    }
    // use ArchiveEntry#getName() to do the conditional stuff...
    IOUtils.copy(input, outputFileStream,10485760);
}
```

Hope I can do some more optimizations, will do later.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `listFiles()` decompresses your `gzip` file in order to be able to scan through the `tar` file to get all the filenames, and then `cp(File, File)` scans it again to position the stream on given file.

What I'd do is use [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html) and do a iterator-like scan on the inputstreams, sort of like this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/path/to/my/file");
ArchiveInputStream input = new ArchiveStreamFactory()
   .createArchiveInputStream(ArchiveStreamFactory.TAR, new GZIPInputStream(is));

ArchiveEntry entry;
while ((entry = input.getNextEntry()) != null) {

    // use ArchiveEntry#getName() to do the conditional stuff...

}
```

Read the javadoc for [`ArchiveInputStream#getNextEntry()`](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/ArchiveInputStream.html#getNextEntry%28%29) and [`ArchiveEntry`](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/ArchiveEntry.html) for more info.

Comment: I tried this one first..., i t needs unzip first and untar next. takes double of the usual time too.

Comment: Edited the answer giving an example how to stream it through a `GZIPInputStream` and pass this stream directly to `commons-compress`. This way everything should be a 1-step process. You can also use a [`GzipCompressorInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/gzip/GzipCompressorInputStream.html#line.47) for this, instead of JDK implementation.

Comment: that looks good earlier I created tar and untarred now it looks same time as tar xzf thankd for the input. I will put revised code in next post

Comment: I have no previledge post answer soon, so I edited the question Thanks npe for the valuable advice

Comment: Well, you don't have to post an answer, you can just accept mine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the performance issue that you've witnessed is that the TAR file format lacks a central directory. But because TrueZIP is a virtual file system and it cannot predict the access pattern of the client application, it has to unzip the entire TAR file to a temporary directory upon first access. This is what happens on TFile.listFiles(). Then you copy the entries from the temporary directory to the target directories. So all in all each entry byte will be read or written four times.

To get best performance, you have two options:

(a) You could switch to the ZIP file format and stick with the TrueZIP File* API. ZIP files have a Central Directory, so reading them does not involve creating temporary files.

(b) You could process the TAR.GZ file as a stream like shown by npe. I would then combine this with a java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream because that implementation is based on fast C code. I would also use TrueZIP's Streams.copy(InputStream, OuputStream) method because it will use multithreading for really fast bulk copying.